# /usr/bin/vlc: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: command-line, bash, video, vlc, helpfile

I tried running vlc in root
but got an error of "VLc can't run in root Sorry"
Then i tried this command sed -i '/' `/usr/bin/vlcs/geteuid/geteppid/' /usr/bin/vlc`
Then i tried running vlc again and got an error `/usr/bin/vlc: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

Comment: Not sure what you wanted to do. /usr/bin/vlc is an ELF binary, not a text file. You cannot just modify something inside without corrupting the executable. Why do you want to run vlc as root?

Comment: I wanted to follow a tutorial. And i need root to run my codes

Comment: I assume the above command comes from there: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125546/how-to-run-vlc-player-in-root ; please notice that this is over 6 years old. Things changed in the meantime. Maybe back then /usr/bin/vlc really was a script that called a binary; today /usr/bin/vlc IS the binary. Also, that "sed" command as you typed it here is broken in many ways; compare with the Stack Exchange article.

Answer (score 3):

With that command, you destroyed your vlc executable; you will have to reinstall the vlc-bin package to get it back to work.

In general, do not execute commands with root privileges (which includes using "sudo") if you don't know exactly what you are doing. The "sed" command is a command-line equivalent of an editor; you edited binary code as a text file. That is bound to fail.

vlc refuses to run as root because many codecs in the past have been known to have security hazards; it's just too easy to open a system widely for attack with a well-prepared media file such as a JPG or an MP4 (to name just a few) that exploits such a security hole.

There is also generally never a good reason to run a media player as root.

Please write what exactly you wanted to achieve, and I am sure we can point you to a better way to get there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i really wanted to run VLC in root. Also how can i reinstall the vlc-bin package.

Comment: At a point i even got a "segmentation error"

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall vlc-bin`

Comment: Yes, of course you get all kinds of errors if you hand-edited a binary file. Never do that.

Comment: What tutorial is that that tells a user to run a media player like "vlc" as root? Or did you just misunderstand what they really mean? I repeat: There is NEVER a good reason to run "vlc" as root. That's why the vlc authors chose to explicitly check that in their program code and refuse to run if it detects that it's running as root.